# Parse W3C Document after reading it using XMLStreamReader API

Tags: java, xml-parsing

This is the code we have currently to parse our input request XML -

```
public byte[] ipReq(byte[] inputRequestBytes) {
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;     
    try {
    byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputRequestBytes);
    Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream));
```

Due to some application requirement, we want to be able to parse the XML document ONLY after reading it, and not process the XML source directly as `java.io.InputStream`. Please suggest me if there is a way to do it using `XMLStreamReader`. This is the code I have so far -

```
public static XMLStreamReader getXMLReader(ByteArrayInputStream input) throws XMLStreamException{
    XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xmlif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isSupportingExternalEntities", false);
    xmlif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.supportDTD", false);
    XMLStreamReader xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(input,"UTF-8");
    return xmlr;
}
```

The application has the required data as a w3c document, so I want to be able to parse the XML data I read with the `XMLStreamReader` by using Document API only. Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don’t really get your requirement, *“we want to be able to parse the XML document ONLY after reading it”* as “reading” the document already implies parsing it as this is what the `XMLStreamReader` does, it parses the XML file but unlike the DOM builder it does not store it.

Now, if you have a stream reader you can use its result for creating a DOM tree by using an identity transformer:

```
XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xmlif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isSupportingExternalEntities", false);
xmlif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.supportDTD", false);
XMLStreamReader xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
// now use the stream reader for creating the DOM tree:
Source src=new StAXSource(xmlr);
DOMResult dst=new DOMResult();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, dst);
Node node = dst.getNode(); // that’s the document node
```

If the objective is to get control over the stream reader and it’s options, that’s the way to go. But if taking your requirement word by word, it’s not the right thing as it will not create the DOM tree *after* reading the XML file; it still does it *while* reading the file and does not much differ from what the DOM builder would do by default (internally).

The main property of the stream reader is that it does *not store* its results but produce events that the code using the stream reader has to handle. So if you really want to read (and parse) the entire file before creating the DOM tree you need to create a temporary storage for the stream reader’s result so you can build the DOM tree after completion.

If you don’t want to re-invent the wheel and implement your own XML data storage, the most natural solution would be to use a DOM tree for the intermediate storage. So the strange but formally correct solution to your requirement, taken word by word, would be to use the code as above, treating the resulting DOM node as the temporary storage and building another DOM tree *after* the reading:

```
src=new DOMSource(node);
DOMResult dst2=new DOMResult();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, dst2);
Node finalResult = dst2.getNode(); // now we build a DOM tree *after* reading
```